# Формирование цитат android

Tags: java, android

Каким лучше элементом сформировать цитаты такого типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вся эта штука формируется в html div блоками

**UPDATE:**

Немного примера блоки с цитатой в html

```html
<div class="js-no-prevent news-comment__speech news-comment__speech_base" id="message_5022370">
   <div class="news-comment__cite">
      <div class="news-comment__inside">
         <div class="news-comment__speech news-comment__speech_small">
            <div class="news-comment__cite">
               <div class="news-comment__inside">
                  <div class="news-comment__speech news-comment__speech_small">
                     <div class="news-comment__cite">
                        <div class="news-comment__inside">
                           <div class="news-comment__speech news-comment__speech_small">водитель быдло не глядя ни на что</div>
                           <div class="news-comment__subtitle news-comment__subtitle_small">
                              <div class="news-comment__flex">
                                 <div class="news-comment__part news-comment__part_1">
                                    <div class="news-comment__name">marsupilami</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="news-comment__part news-comment__part_2"></div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <p>Не, - не читал...<br />
                        Человек мля,проблему затронул на всеобщее обозрение.
                  </div>
                  <div class="news-comment__subtitle news-comment__subtitle_small">
                     <div class="news-comment__flex">
                        <div class="news-comment__part news-comment__part_1">
                           <div class="news-comment__name">1994837</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-comment__part news-comment__part_2"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <p>он проблему затронул быдловатым поведением?? так решать проблемы нельзя
         </div>
         <div class="news-comment__subtitle news-comment__subtitle_small">
            <div class="news-comment__flex">
               <div class="news-comment__part news-comment__part_1">
                  <div class="news-comment__name">marsupilami</div>
               </div>
               <div class="news-comment__part news-comment__part_2"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p>А как? Милицию вызывать?</p>
</div>
```

Как выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас что есть:

1. Добавлен ListView
2. Для него сделан адаптер

В адаптере уже все сделано что касается имени, даты, лайка и т.к далее, не предусмотрена лишь разметка под комментарий где есть цитаты как показано на скриншоте.

Интересует как лучше(и правильно) построить такое отображение, мб необходимо наследоваться от TextView и там чего нибудь переделать?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду чем отображать? если эти данные изначально в виде html то можно попробовать это делать посредством webview

Comment: Да, оно должно построить ListView где элементы будет такие вот цитаты

Comment: Ну вот Вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос. Формироваться должно в ListView где рекурсивно будут еще несколько ListView

Comment: user_21 думаю стоит использовать RecyclerView, создать отдельно xml файл макета для шапки [фото кота, никнейм, время] и файл макета для вложенных элементов (картинка в полную высоту с серым background и узкой шириной - имитация серой полоски, справа LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией, содержимое: пустой LinearLayout(чтобы можно в него было загрузить прошлое сообщение), текст текущего сообщения, никнейм ).

Comment: user_21, не знаю каким образом вы будете получать данные, может быть вы создадите свою структуру и передадите адаптеру список таких структур, в адаптере будете извлекать данные и формировать View конечные элементы

Comment: Достаточно сложно ответить на ваш вопрос, потому что мало входных данных. 
Приведите пример html кода, который к вам приходит, отрисуйте структуру ListView, которую вы хотите видеть в итоге.
Я бы попробовал прокачать TextView, что бы он каким-то похожим образом отмечал цитаты

Comment: Немного уточнил вопрос и добавил описания, сейчас думаю должно быть ясно что именно надо.